# ASP.NET : when I click the submit button, it doesn't log in directly, but when I again click submit, it logs in. How to fix it?

Tags: asp.net

This is my login section

```
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="form-container sign-up">
        <form method="post">
            <!--Register action руу post хүсэлт илгээнэ-->
            <h1>Бүртгэл үүсгэх</h1>
            <div class="social-icons">
                <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>дээрх төрөлөөр бүртгүүлэх эсвэл</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="usname">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="passwd">
            <button type="submit" asp-action="UserRegister">Бүртгүүлэх</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container sign-in">
        <form method="post">   <!--Login action руу post хүсэлт илгээнэ-->
            <h1>Нэвтрэх</h1>
            <div class="social-icons">
                <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>дээрх төрлөөр нэвтрэх эсвэл</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" asp-for="Username"> <!--LoginModel ийн Username руу утга дамжуулна-->
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" asp-for="Password"> <!--LoginModel ийн Password-->
            <a href="#">Нууц үгээ мартсан уу?</a>
            <button type="submit">Нэвтрэх</button>
            @{
                if (Users.msg == "successUser")
                {
                    <p style="color:green; font-size:1rem; text-align:center;">Амжилттай бүртгэгдэлээ</p>
                }
                else if (Users.msg == "failedUser")
                {
                    <p style="color:red; font-size:1rem; text-align:center">Алдаа гарлаа</p>
                }
            }
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--toggle хийх хэсэг-->
    <div class="toggle-container">
        <div class="toggle">
            <div class="toggle-panel toggle-left">
                <h1>Тавтай морилно уу!</h1>
                <p>Буцаад нэвтрэх хэсэгрүү шилжих</p>
                <button class="hidden" id="login">Нэвтрэх хэсэг</button>
            </div>
            <div class="toggle-panel toggle-right">
                <h1>Сайнуу, Хэрэглэгч!</h1>
                <p>Сайтад бүртгүүлж дараагын холбоосруу нэвтрэхийн тулд бүртгэл үүсгэнэ үү!</p>
                <button class="hidden" id="register">Бүртгүүлэх хэсэг</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller `Login` action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        // Validate the user's credentials against your database or any other data store
        Users user = _userRepository.GetUser(model.Username, model.Password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            // Create claims for the authenticated user
            var claims = new List<Claim>
                             {
                                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
                                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, _userRepositor[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJwzx.png)y.GetRoleName(user.RoleId)),
                                 // Add any additional claims as needed
                             };

            // Create identity with claims
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            // Create principal with identity
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

            HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal);
            // Sign in the user
            //await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal);

            // Make sure the user is signed in before checking roles
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Redirect to the originally requested URL or a default URL
                if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Admin", "Account");
                }
                else if (User.IsInRole("User"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Userpage", "Account");
                }
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

My goal is to navigate from the login area to the admin window by performing a login action. But I get an error when entering the login username and password and pressing the login button, there is an error to enter the login information again and click the button. But I need to enter login information once and login directly, please help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put console log statement in your code and debuggers as well. The open developer tools and debug your line of codes carefully, It must be an exception. Hopefully, this will solve your problem.